# Can specific microcontrollers be used as secure element?

Tags: microcontroller

After learning that there can be set a security bit to prevent reading from Arduino microcontroller, thought about if could it be used as a secure element kinda thing? Storing all kinds of digital signatures, passwords and signing with them using a pin like Ledger Nano or other hardware wallets etc.

Comment: yes, it could be used for that

Comment: There are microcontrollers designed specifically for this - or you could use a "smart card"

Comment: See e.g. yubikey 's line of hardware tokens

Answer (score 3):

Read out protection is a way to protect code, but it is meant to keep out curious hobbyists from reading your code, it won't protect from determined hackers that want to clone the product or crack the secrets inside.